# Service Fabric WcfCommunicationListener With IServiceCollection (IOC). .Net core 1

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I've been searching for an example using WcfCommunicationListener and IServiceCollection, in the same way that a stateless service Listener makes a call to ConfigureServices so as to setup the Container.

I'm stuck with .Net Core 1 for this

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks in advance